# Twilio Studio Runtime Function Wait or Sleep

Tags: twilio

In twilio studio I have 2 messages that goes one after the other.

I need a 5 or 10 seconds wait time between these messages.

How can I do it in twilio studio?
or 
How can I write a function that waits 10 seconds, runs after that and I send the other message.

I tried to use

```
setTimeout(function(){
   response ="This is response";

},5000);
```

But this did not worked at Twilio, 
I also tried `wait(5000);`
but it gave error that wait is not defined.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe my answer can help you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977722/how-can-i-add-pause-to-twilio-studio-say-play-widget/51031632#51031632)

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could use a Twilio Function to delay the message here, but Twilio Functions do time out after 5 seconds. (If you really need 10 seconds, you could queue this function up to run twice.)

Here's a Function that will wait 5 seconds and then return:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(null, {});
  }, 5000)
}
```

The key is that you trigger the `callback` function within the callback to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks @philnash, we are hitting our sms rate limits very quickly. We are conducting surveys (question/answer x 15) and implementing a small delay has helped us avoid that error.