# Make Twilio wait 15 seconds before continuing flow

Tags: twilio, liquid

I'm trying to get Twilio to **use a webhook for 15 seconds** (call on Zoho) and then **return to the IVR**. I found different functions to make it wait, but none seem to work! Does anybody know how to do this? Again, it just needs to wait while calling the webhook and **after the 15 seconds** continue the flow of the IVR.

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: A little more information about your problem would help us answer it. [Here are some hints on asking questions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The "use a webhook for 15 seconds" confuses me, as the webhook should return quick, indeed 15 secs Twilio's timeout for webhooks. If you want to put the user on hold for 15 secs (in silence) and then as the next question of the IVR you could do <Pause length="15"/><Redirect>http://url-that-asks-next-IVR-question</Redirect>. Just be careful, 15 secs of silence could make the user to hung up, maybe you could play an audio that is 15 secs long. It would be <Play>15-sec-audio.mp3</Play><Redirect>http://url-that-asks-next-IVR-question</Redirect>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Juan!! Basically what I need it to do is ring our agents in Zoho CRM for 15 seconds (give or take, it can be shorter) and then return to the Twilio IVR. Is the <Pause length = "15"> script all I need to put before the next step of the IVR? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977722/how-can-i-add-pause-to-twilio-studio-say-play-widget/51031632#51031632

Comment: Can you not use `<Dial>` to call your agent with a `timeout` set to 15 seconds and an `action` that continues the IVR?

Comment: Expanding on what doesn't work would be helpful.  I'm doing almost exactly this except I do the pause before the call is answered so it rings a given number of seconds for an operator and then goes to IVR.   If the operator becomes available I use the REST call to redirect the call.