# Twilio Studio - how to play back gathered digits individually with a pause?

Tags: twilio, ivr

I'm using this {{widgets.gather_1.Digits | split: "" | join: " "}} for playing each gathered digit seprately but it says too fast. I want to say it slower. so the we can easily understand.but i dont know how also Can we make it like it says first 4 digit then take a pause like 3 seconds then again it says next 4 digit and so on. If anyone knows please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Studio? If so, the this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977722/how-can-i-add-pause-to-twilio-studio-say-play-widget) might help you:

> If you're using the new Polly voices, you need to embed SSML in the Say text area, such as:
>
> ```
> <speak>Hello. <break time="5s"/> Goodbye.</speak>
> ```